# Cropped image is getting zoomed in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an application in which i am scaling my image of(360,480)to (320,480),then cropping the image.It is working fine.But when we got the image it is getting a little zoomed type image.projected up to front.Here is how i am doing it.`

```
[self imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(160.0f,240.0f)];
```

and my defenition is -

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self cropimage:newImage];
    return newImage;
}
```

and in cropimage i am doing like this -

```
-(void)cropimage:(UIImage *)image
{

   CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(20,100,280,200);
     CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage* croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
         CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    NSData *pictureData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedImage)];
}
```

can anybody find out what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: my first guess: is the scale of original uiimage equal to 1.0 if not you might need to modify cropRect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing image.scale for the scale instead of 0.0 to force it to use the passed in image scale.

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self cropimage:newImage];
    return newImage;
}
```